Dynamically add widget elements to a QVBoxLayout in a ScrollArea that updates the scroll bar
I want to have a scroll area that I can add Widgets to and as needed, the vertical scroll bar accounts for additions or removals of said elements. Inside the QScrollArea, I have a QVBoxLayout.
What ends up happening is that my Widget elements get 'cut off' by the limited area with no scrolling capability - even with Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn (It's just greyed out).
Image showing the cut off element and the greyed out scrollbar - the ideal behavior is for the scrollbar to allow viewing of all the elements:

Secondly, below is a picture of my custom QWidget in question that I want to be displayed inside the area. As you can see in the picture above, the second half (Output Location) isn't visible, the elements overlap one another instead of being placed one after the other.
Image showing the entire custom QWidget that I want displayed inside the layout of the QScrollArea:

Below is the relevant code for the MainWindow that handles adding the widget elements to the layout. The ideal future functionality is a button that dynamically adds/removes these elements. I need the ScrollArea to be scrollable, instead of greyed out/not working.
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->bBrowse,
            &QPushButton::clicked,
            this,
            &MainWindow::openBlenderLocation);

    connect(ui->strBtn,
            &QPushButton::clicked,
            this,
            &MainWindow::writeString);


    QWidget *central = new QWidget;
    QScrollArea *scroll = ui->scrollArea;
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(central);

    scroll->setWidget(central);
    scroll->setWidgetResizable(true);

    ProjectRow *pRow1 = new ProjectRow(this);
    ProjectRow *pRow2 = new ProjectRow(this);
    ProjectRow *pRow3 = new ProjectRow(this);

    layout->addWidget(pRow1);
    layout->addWidget(pRow2);
    layout->addWidget(pRow3);

    scroll->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);



}

Below is my ProjectRow.cpp. All of it's elements were made in the designer.
#include "projectrow.h"
#include "ui_projectrow.h"

ProjectRow::ProjectRow(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::ProjectRow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

ProjectRow::~ProjectRow()
{
    delete ui;
}


I've tried setting the verticalScrollBarPolicy to AlwaysOn, and as can be visible in the screenshot, it's now only greyed out. I am not sure why I cannot get the ScrollArea to scroll, and why the vertical layout is overlapping my elements instead of placing them one after the other.

Please provide a proper [mre], specifically the ProjectRow class. Right now it seems you're not properly taking into account appropriate size hints.

Also, I assume that you're creating the UI in Designer, and in that case the scroll area already has a container widget set, so you should preferably use that, not create another one.
